# A question on the number of involutions in a 2-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a classification of groups of order $2^n$ and exponent $4$ containing exactly $2^{n-1}-1$ involutions?

Comment: I haven't thought about it at all, but an immediate question is do you mean at least $2^{n-1}-1$ or exactly $2^{n-1}-1$ involutions? (How many months have $28$ days?)

Comment: According to the introduction of the following paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-122-02/S0002-9939-1994-1242094-7/S0002-9939-1994-1242094-7.pdf, all finite groups in which at least 11/32 of the elements are involutions have been classified.

Comment: It looks like https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/17/0/17_0_88/_pdf is exactly on this question, but it a bit hard to read.

Comment: Verret: Many thanks! Is there a source describing more precisely these classes?

Comment: @verret the linked article of Rusin (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102785075) considers finite groups in which at least 11/32 of the pairs commute. How does it relate to have at least 11/32 elements of order 2?

Comment: @YCor, I have the same question.

Comment: @MariusTarnauceanu At the end of the paper by Miller he says that there are fifteen infinite families. Their description are interspersed throughout the text, but in old terminology.

Answer (score 3):

Miller, G.A. Groups of order $g$ containing $g/2-1$ involutions. Tôhuku math. J. 17, (1920) 88-102 (https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/17/0/17_0_88/_pdf )
is on exactly this question.

The examples are described throughout the paper, although in slightly out-dated terminology.